# Getting list of controls inside a specific div in .NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, asp.net-ajax, html, controls

How to Get list of controls inside a specific div in ASP.NET

Comment: Your question is unclear - do you want to do this client side or server side?

Comment: on server side ..... not in js or jq ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing your div has an ID attribute (say yourDiv) and runat="server", and providing you're using C#, try:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < yourDiv.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(yourDiv.Controls[i].ToString());
    }
```

to list the types of the controls contained within the div.

Answer (score 3):

Every asp.net Control has a parameter Controls

```
foreach ( Control ctrl in myDivCtrl.Controls ) { string ctrlId = ctrl.ID; }
```